# What module is used to create the table of contents in Drupal documentation?

Tags: 7

I want to create a table of contents for sections of my site like Drupal.org has for their documentation. For example [on this page](http://drupal.org/documentation/install), there is the "Table of Contents" block on the right hand side. What module is used to do this?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That block is the "Book navigation" block implemented by the Book module in [book_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_block_view/7), and defined in [book_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!book!book.module/function/book_block_info/7).

The copyright block that appears right after the "Book navigation" block is implemented in [drupalorg_handbook.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupalorg.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/drupalorg_handbook/drupalorg_handbook.module), which is a custom module used to run Drupal.org, and its sub-domains.